# Access VBA - Selecting newest option in combobox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database with three tables: Employees, Consultations, and Customers.  Here are the relationships:

Employees<--->Consultations

Consultations<--->Customers

I have a form for entering consultations (called "Consultations"), and the user can select the Customer from a combo box.  This then displays the customer information on the form in a read-only format.  If the user needs to update the customer information (name, type, department, etc.) they can click a button that opens another form to that customer's record.  They can update the info, then close that form, and the "Consultations" form is updated with the new customer information.  This all works fine.

I also want users to be able to enter a new customer record if they don't exist in the customers table.  Currently, the user can click on a button, and a form is opened where they can enter all of the new customer information, called "Add-Customer".  Once they close the form, the "Consultations" form is displayed again.  Here is where I am having issues.

What I want to happen is that after the user enters the new customer, the new customer should be selected in the combo box.  The combo box is holding the customer's "LastName, FirstName".  I was able to get the new record to appear in the combo box, but the user still needs to manually select it.  I want this to happen automatically.

Here is my code that runs when the user clicks OK on the "Add-Customer" form:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

'save customer record
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

'make add-customer form invisible
Me.Visible = False

'requery the customerlastname field on consultations form
DoCmd.Requery "CustomerLastName"

'close add-customer form
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Add-Customer"

End Sub
```

I tried adding a variable that stores the ID of the new record, then tried to have the combo box select that record, but couldn't get it to work.  I've removed that from the above code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: Realizing you are working with a second form - which is not a subform, here is one possible solution.

You will need to pass the new value back to the original form. You can do this in several ways: (a) a global variable; (b) a hidden textbox; (c) create public function in main form.  I chose to use a hidden field.

I assume you are opening the ‘Add’ form as modal. If not, then you need to do that.
(You will need to change the following code to use your combobox name and form name)

1. Add a hidden textbox on the main form i.e. named txtNameHidden
2. In the close code for the 'Add' form, add the following:

   Forms!frmMyMainForm!txtNameHidden = me.txtName  ' The value as it will appear in the combobox
3. In the Main form, after the line of code that opened the form, add the following code:

   Me.cboNames.Value = Me. txtNameHidden

I am curious about your code 'DoCmd.Requery "CustomerLastName"' - does this work? How does it know to reference the control on the main form?

Comment: I looked at that article, but it doesn't help me in this case.  I won't know how many items will be in the combo box when a new customer is added.  A new customer could be the 9th item, and then another one could be the 25th item.  So using an absolute number there won't work.

Comment: You need to spin thru the list in the combobox to find the matching name, then set the 'Selected' option. Do you know how to do that, or do I need to post code for you?

Comment: If you could post code for that, that would be awesome!!

Comment: First I need a little info: 1. Is the add form Modal? 2. All you want is for the ComboBox to show the just-added name as the default (i.e. currently selected)?

Comment: Yes to both questions!

Comment: I updated the answer. But I am curious about your code 'DoCmd.Requery "CustomerLastName"' - does that work? How does it know to reference the control on the main form?

Comment: Your answer worked, thank you!  It turns out that the Requery does not work at that point.  I changed it to run when the main form opens.